# htaccess rewriterule not working on shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The htaccess rule

```html
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$    index.php?link=$1 [L]
```

should redirect from url.com/user to url.com/index.php?link=user. It does so on my local server but not on my shared hosting. I know that custom htaccess files are enabled, because the second rule in my htaccess file (see below) works fine.

```html
# URL rewrite
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?link=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(compare)/?$ index.php?link=compare&id=$1 [L]
```

Any ideas, why the first rewrite rule doesn't work?

The error says:

"The requested URL /user was not found on this server."

Comment: What URL are you going to in order to make the second rule work? Is the htaccess file in the right folder/

Comment: url.com/compare is the url i'm typing in the second case. the htaccess file is in the root folder where it belongs; no other htaccess files are in any subfolders.

Comment: We had some .inc files in the same folder, which somehow disturbed the htaccess forwarding. I do not know how, but by renaming these .inc files to .php, the problem is now solved.